# Search within models/active record in Yii

Tags: yii

If I have something like:

```
$posts = Post::model()->findAll();
```

How could I search within $posts for a post by primary key? (As opposed to running a separate database query since the data is already loaded)

---

**Background:**

I'm loading data from an external source, based on the primary key of a model. So I run a lookup to find all the models that need updating, and then make a request to the external source, and update the models.

The results (~100) are sent back as an unlabeled array of objects (one of the variables in the object is the primary key), so it seems appropriate to iterate that array, and then update the values on the existing model I've already loaded from the database and then save each item.

I'm not against using another method to get all this accomplished, this just seems like the most maintainable way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess simply looping through all posts would be an option:

```
 for($posts as $post){
      if($post->pk=='pk')
         //do staff...
 }
```

alternatively, if it is possible, this is prefereable:

```
$post=Post::model()->findByPK('pk');
```

Comment: Well, this means I need to iterate both the results array and the models array for each item, as opposed to one of the two having an existing index.

Comment: Actually, I'm already iterating the models once to generate the external request, I could just create a reverse lookup index for the models array there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A little blurred answer but I think it might be good for you: there's a way to tell yii that when it loads records using findAll() (like you did), to return the array of objects using a specific column as the key for the array elements. Be sure to use a unique column though otherwise you'll get possible overwriting of array elements... .
Search for 'index' in [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr). I don't have a ready made sample code to give you.

Answer (score 0):

array_filter()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Compliments of SJFriedl